# Why is remix giving me gas estimation errors when I am sending more gas than the transaction needs?

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, gas

I am running a contract in remix and only my getBalance() function is working. Specifically my requestFlashLoan, approveUSDC, and approveDAI are all failing due to gas. I sent the transaction even after Remix gave me the warning so I could debug but that even shows that the gas im sending is more than the transaction and I have sent more than enough USDC and DAI to both my mock DEX and my current contract. Any reason I am getting this? I have both my flashLoan contract, my mock dex, and the remix error I tried to debug with.

This is my flashLoan contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

interface IDex {
    function depositUSDC(uint256 _amount) external;
    function depostDAI(uint256 _amount) external;
    function buyDAI() external;
    function sellDAI() external;
}

contract FlashLoanArbitrage is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;

    address private immutable daiAddress = 0x75Ab5AB1Eef154C0352Fc31D2428Cef80C7F8B33;
    address private immutable usdcAddress = 0x65aFADD39029741B3b8f0756952C74678c9cEC93;
    address private immutable dexContractAddress = 0x4A96CEEc9eF026921A836211830E47203D6bB4A3;

    IERC20 private dai;
    IERC20 private usdc;
    IDex private dexContract;

    constructor(address _addressProvider) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)) 
    {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        // custom loginc

        dexContract.depositUSDC(1000000000); // 1000 USDC
        dexContract.buyDAI();
        dexContract.depostDAI(dai.balanceOf(address(this)));
        dexContract.sellDAI();
        // By this point, this contract owes the flashloaned amount + premiums
        // Ensure your contract has enough to repay these amounts


        // Approve the Pool contract allowance to "pull" or take, the owed amount
        uint256 amountOwned = amount + premium;
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwned);

        return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {

        address recieverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = '';
        uint16 referralCode = 0;


        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            recieverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    // Before we request loan, we need to approve an amount of USDC and DAI so the contract can approve some amount
    // Need to be available on the blockchain before arbitrage is run
    function approveUSDC(uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
        return usdc.approve(dexContractAddress, _amount);
    }

    function allowanceUSDC() external view returns (uint256) {
        return usdc.allowance(address(this), dexContractAddress);
    }

    function approveDAI(uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
        return dai.approve(dexContractAddress, _amount);
    }

    function allowanceDAI() external view returns (uint256) {
        return dai.allowance(address(this), dexContractAddress);
    }
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns(uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 'Only the contract owner can call this function');
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Mock DEX:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract Dex {
    address payable public owner;

    // Aave ERC20 Token addresses on Goerli network
    address private immutable daiAddress =
        0x75Ab5AB1Eef154C0352Fc31D2428Cef80C7F8B33;
    address private immutable usdcAddress =
        0x65aFADD39029741B3b8f0756952C74678c9cEC93;

    IERC20 private dai;
    IERC20 private usdc;

    // exchange rate indexes
    uint256 dexARate = 90;
    uint256 dexBRate = 100;

    // keeps track of individuals' dai balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public daiBalances;

    // keeps track of individuals' USDC balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public usdcBalances;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        dai = IERC20(daiAddress);
        usdc = IERC20(usdcAddress);
    }

    function depositUSDC(uint256 _amount) external {
        usdcBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        uint256 allowance = usdc.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
        usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function depositDAI(uint256 _amount) external {
        daiBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        uint256 allowance = dai.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
        dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function buyDAI() external {
        uint256 daiToReceive = ((usdcBalances[msg.sender] / dexARate) * 100) *
            (10**12);
        dai.transfer(msg.sender, daiToReceive);
    }

    function sellDAI() external {
        uint256 usdcToReceive = ((daiBalances[msg.sender] * dexBRate) / 100) /
            (10**12);
        usdc.transfer(msg.sender, usdcToReceive);
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract owner can call this function"
        );
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Remix Error:

```
[block:9186047 txIndex:6]from: 0x88e...05305to: FlashLoanArbitrage.approveUSDC(uint256) 0xa63...2FdE4value: 0 weidata: 0x5f8...d7840logs: 0hash: 0xcfd...86740
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0x452bb73ca7a22f407dc54cbec622bfd4af095699464e908719b94c699f89adc7
from    0x88e6Bc4Fcb2665b2c40a43510DfCB2aF9ea05305
to  FlashLoanArbitrage.approveUSDC(uint256) 0xa633069D1d126C5e40C5103EEC74A0925692FdE4
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    27009 gas 
input   0x5f8...d7840
decoded input   {
    "uint256 _amount": "25000000"
}
decoded output   - 
logs    []
val 0 wei
```